# Suppose $f$ is analytic on a connected open set $D$ and $f'(z)= 0$ for all $z \in D$

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi: I'm going through an intro to complex analysis book and of the exercises is  to show that $f(z)$ is constant given that it is analytic on a connected open set D and $f'(z) = 0    ~~\forall  z \in D $. Thanks for any help. It's not homework. I'm just getting into complex variables.

Comment: If $f$ is analytic on $D$, then it has a convergent power series expansion on $D$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations must help you.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: As J.J correctly pointed out, $f'(z)$ is already assumed to be $0$ in the whole of $D$. The problem I solved was: 
Assume f'(z)=0 in a connected, open subset of the region where $f$ is analytic. I will try to solve the actual problems posted, and not the ones inside of my febrile head.

If $f(z)$ is analytic , then so is $f'(z)$. Since $f'(z)$ agrees with the function $g(z)=0$ on the non-discrete set D (an open set in $\mathbb C$ is not discrete, i.e., it contains limit points, since it contains non-empty open balls), then $f'(z)=g(z)=0$ in the region D (by the often-called Identity theorem). Now you can use some form of Cauchy-Riemann to show $f(z)$ must be constant. Let $f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. Then you have that: $$u_x=v_y=0 ; u_y=-v_x=0 $$ . Then you see that both $u ,v$ are constant, so that $f(z)$ itself is constant.

EDIT 2: As pointed out, we never used the fact that $D$ is connected. We can use that, for $\mathbb C $ , or actually for Euclidean space in general, connectedness and path-connectedness are the same: So , we are given $f'(z)=0=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ in $D$. Assume, by contradiction that $f$ is not constant; say $U(x,y)$ is not constant; say $U(a,.) \neq U(b,.)$. Then we can use a version of the Mean Value Theorem applied to a path between the two unequal values, which would force $U_x \neq 0$ at some point in the path. We cannot use this argument unless we have path-connectedness --which in this case is the same as connectedness.

Comment: thanks. I will print it out, make sure I understand and then give your answer a check. it's much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, mark, good luck with your (hopefully not too) Complex studies :).

Comment: $f'(z) = 0$ in $D$ was assumed in the question, thus the deduction in the beginning is not needed.

Comment: @J.J , you're right; I keep projecting my own questions into other's posts.

Comment: @mark leeds: please read J.J's comment. There is nothing wrong in the post, but there is an unnecessary part , re the Identity theorem. Still, you may want to read up on it, it is an important theorem in Complex analysis.

Comment: You have not used connectedness in your answer, so you cannot conclude that $f$ is constant.

Comment: @copper.hat O.K, I think a relatively-straightforward argument would show $f(z)$ is constant component-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach:

The key fact here is:
If $D$ is open and connected, it is path connected. In fact, the path can be taken to be piecewise smooth.

Let $z_1,z_2 \in D$ and let $\gamma:[0,1] \to D$ be a piecewise smooth connecting $z_1,z_2$.

Suppose $t_0 = 0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n = 1$ are such that $\gamma$ is smooth on each interval.

Let $\phi(t) = f(\gamma(t))$, and note that $\phi'(t) = f'(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) = 0$ for all $t \notin \{t_0,...,t_n\}$. If follows that $\phi(t_k) = \phi(t_{k+1})$ for $k=0,...,n-1$, and from this it follows that $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$.

Since $z_1,z_2 \in D$ were arbitrary, it follows that $f$ is constant on $D$.

Comment: How about using a version of the Mean Value theorem restricted to a path ? Then if , say, U(x,.) is not constant, then $U(a,.)-U(b,.) \neq 0$

Comment: it looks like there's extra material for me to print out and study so thanks for addendums and explanations. stackechange has quite impressive and generous people on it. all the best.